# context switch in the source

Tags: linux, multithreading, g++

The folowing source is an queue class :

```
template<typename T>
class mpmc_bounded_queue
{
public:
    bool enqueue(T const& data)
    {
        cell_t* cell;
        size_t pos  ;
        for (;;)
        {
            pos = enqueue_pos_ ;
            cell = &buffer_[pos & buffer_mask_];
            size_t seq = cell->sequence_;
            intptr_t dif = (intptr_t)seq - (intptr_t)pos;
            if (dif == 0)
            {
                //spot A
                if (__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&enqueue_pos_,pos,pos+1) )
                    break;
            } else if (dif < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }else{
                pos = enqueue_pos_;
            }
        }
        // spot B 
        cell->data_ = data;
        cell->sequence_ = pos + 1 ;
        return true;
    } //enqueue
private:
    struct cell_t
    { 
        size_t     sequence_;
        T          data_;
    };
} ;
```

In RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.0 x86_64 , Is it possible that context switch 
happened in finishing __sync_bool_compare_and_swap ( spot A) but not yet to
execute cell->data_ = data (spot B) ?

I've told that context switch would happened in like recv , send , usleep,
something to do with I/O function , in this case , while many threads execute 
enqueue , there is not possible that there exist an possibility a thread finish 
__sync_bool_compare_and_swap return true but at this important moment it is context switch out before it execute cell->data_ = data , Is it true ?
or context switch was not possible happened between spot A  and spot B  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it true ?

Yes: a context switch can happen at any point between A and B.

That shouldn't affect the algorithm though, which appears to be correct: if `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` returned true, then you have *atomically* reserved the cell at `pos`, and nobody else will interfere with that cell, so whether the context switch happens between A and B or not is irrelevant.

Comment: you are right , if use this with semaphore ,then it would has a little trouble , suppose t1,t2,t3 execute enqueue , t1 has __sync_bool_compare_and_swap done first , and switched out before spot B , t2 and t3 finish  enqueue function and do sem_post , suppose t4 sem_wait  is waked up , at this case , t4 dequeue will return false because that position should be filled by t1 , which is switched out !!!

Comment: At this case , those threads which sem_wait would be waked up but dequeue will return false , then semaphore is not suitable while using this queue class .